# Updating variable in Angular component when another variable has changed

Tags: angular, data-binding, eventemitter, ngonchanges

I try something like this:

**component.ts**

```
displayName: string;
email: string = `user+${this.displayName}@domain.com`;
```

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="displayName" name="displayName">
<input type="email" [value]="email" name="email">
```

`email` is updated once when the app is loaded but not when `displayName` changes.

Do I need to use `EventEmitter` or `ngOnChanges` or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Reason is that `displayName` property is used to **initialize** `email` property value, hence consecutive reads of `email` property returns same value, no matter `displayName` is changed or not. instead what you need is to write a getter for `email` property and return value calculated **based on** `displayName`

Try following

```
get email(): string { return `user+${this.displayName}@domain.com`; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by using `ngModelCange`

**component.ts**

```
displayName: string;
email: string = null;

onKey(event: any) {
  this.email = (this.displayName === undefined || this.displayName === null) ? null : `user+${this.displayName}@domain.com`;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="displayName" (ngModelChange)="onKey($event)" name="displayName">
<input type="email" [value]="email" name="email">
```

You can also use `keydown` instead of `ngModelChange`. It has the same behaviour, at least in this case.